# guilds.verificationLevel is not able to properly do a custom output

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I was trying to enhance my aboutserver command in Discord.JS, I realized you can customize the outputs, like if the output was 1 you can make it say something else instead of 1, like verification level is low. I did this for my explicitContentFilter & the verificationLevel parts of my command, they managed to get out the custom message but only got out the last one for each part of the code. When I adjusted the moderation or eCF, the custom messages just stayed the same when running the command.

I've tried removing the `backticks` from the code, 
`` (if (serv.explicitContentFilter = `1`) ``
=> 
`` (`if (serv.explicitContentFilter = 1) ``
But a change was not made. I tried adding the `?Number:1` to the end like this : `if (serv.explicitContentFilter?Question:1)` { and the code did not work, it stayed stuck all the time and I even tried to adjust where the code went, I tried removing the `else` portion of the code at the end. A change was not made.

```
async run(message, args){
    if (message.channel instanceof discord.DMChannel) return message.channel.send('This command cannot be executed here.')
    else
    var serv = message.guild

    if (serv.explicitContentFilter = `0`) {
        var eFC = "Don't Scan Any messages";
    } else {
        var eFC = serv.explicitContentFilter;
    }
    if (serv.explicitContentFilter = `1`) {
        var eFC = "Scan for users without a role.";
    } else {
        var eFC = serv.explicitContentFilter;
    }
    if (serv.explicitContentFilter = `2`) {
        var eFC = "Scan every message";
    } else {
        var eFC = serv.explicitContentFilter;
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (serv.verificationLevel = `4`) {
        var verL = "Intense (Verified Account & Verified Phone linked)";
    } else {
        var verL = serv.verificationLevel;
    }    

    if (serv.verificationLevel = `3`) {
        var verL = "Secure (Verified Account & Guild member for 10+ minutes)";
    } else {
        var verL = serv.verificationLevel;
    }    

    if (serv.verificationLevel = `2`) {
        var verL = "Medium (Verified Account for 5 minutes+)";
    } else {
        var verL = serv.verificationLevel;
    }    

    if (serv.verificationLevel = `1`) {
        var verL = "Low (Verified Account)";
    } else {
        var verL = serv.verificationLevel;
    }    

    if (serv.verificationLevel = `0`) {
        var verL = "None (No Restriction)";
    } else {
        var verL = serv.verificationLevel;
    }    

    var myInfo = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`${serv.name}'s guild info`,`${serv.iconURL}`)
        .addField(`AFK Channel`,`${serv.afkChannel}`,true)
        .addField(`AFK Timeout`,`${serv.afkTimeout}s`,true)
        .addField(`Channels`,`${serv.channels.size}`,true)
        .addField(`Creation of Guild`,`${serv.createdAt}`,true)
        .addField(`Explicit Content Filter Level`, eFC,true)
        .addField(`How much members`,`${serv.memberCount}`,true)
        .addField(`Moderation Level`,`${serv.mfaLevel}`,true)
        .addField(`Owner`,`${serv.owner}`,true)
        .addField(`Region`,`${serv.region}`,true)
        .addField(`Roles`,`${serv.roles}`,true)
        .addField(`Verification Level`, verL,true)
        .addField(`AFK Channel`,`${serv.afkChannel}`,true)
        .setColor(0xf0e5da)
        .setFooter('p!aboutserver')
        .setThumbnail(`${message.guild.iconURL}`)


        message.channel.sendEmbed(myInfo);

}

}
```

I expect the bot to be able to find the guild's verification level and send a custom output back into the embeded message `if verification level is 3 then the custom output is verification level is medium`

The problem is the bot says the same custom message and when the guild's moderation settings are changed for the specific settings, it says the wrong message / the same message it said before the settings are changed.

Comment: This Questions still seems to be unresolved, could you please mark a Answer as accepted, or self answer if you have found the Solution? @SomePerson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```js
if (serv.verificationLevel = `2`) {
        var verL = "Medium (Verified Account for 5 minutes+)";
    } else {
        var verL = serv.verificationLevel;
    }
```

Is checking for regular text.

Discord.JS's way of finding verification levels on guilds uses numbers.

Think of it like this.

`0` ≠ 0

`0` ≠ Number

0  = 0

0  = Number

Simply remove the tillas from what each value is asking for, and like @PLASMA chicken said, put `==` or even use `===` as using `=` in `if` statements in some instances reverse what they're looking for.

Comment: In JS doing `0 == '0'` or `0 == \`0\`` or `false == 0` will actually return true.
That's why its recommended to use `===` wich does check types, too.
Meaning `false === 0` will return false

Answer (score 5):

To check against something use `==`, `=` is assigning to a variable.

Comment: You could even use `===`, use this article to know what's the difference: https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a